# char to int conversion in host device with CUDA

Tags: c++, c, cuda, ascii

I have been having trouble converting from a single character to an integer while in the host function of my CUDA program. After the line -

```
token[j] = token[j] * 10 + (buf[i] - '0' );
```

I use cuda-gdb check the value for token[j], and I always get different numbers that do not seem to have a pattern. I have also tried simple casting, not multiplying by ten (which I saw in another thread), not subtracting '0', and I always seem to get a different result. Any help would be appreciated. This is my first time posting on stack overflow, so give me a break if my formatting is awful.

-A fellow struggling coder

```
 __global__ void rread(unsigned int *table, char *buf, int *threadbytes, unsigned int *token) {
         int i = 0;
         int j = 0;
         *token = NULL;
         int tid = threadIdx.x;
         unsigned int key;
         char delim = ' ';
         for(i = tid * *threadbytes; i <(tid * *threadbytes) + *threadbytes ; i++)
         {
                 if (buf[i] != delim) { //check if its not a delim
                         token[j] = token[j] * 10 + (buf[i] - '0' );
```

Comment: buf[i] - '0' will work only for numeric characters till 9 then you get garbage. I also don't see what's that *10 for

Comment: The character in this case, buf[i], will always be a single numeric digit, which mean 0-9. The *10 is not important, even if I get rid of that I still get different results.

Comment: If I change the code to:
token[j] = (buf[i] - '0');
I still have the same problem. Even though in gdb, when I type:
p buf[i] - '0'
I get the correct number, but something happens with the assignment

Comment: It seems that all the threads will write at the same location `j=0`, so leading to a race condition?

Comment: Forget j = 0, I now realize that every thread has access to token! That is a huge problem. I don't know if that is why the assignment isn't working properly though. Is there a way I can declare a local array in each thread (each array is only int long, so there isn't a memory constraint), and then convert using that? I was having some type casting issues before.

Comment: That's right, race condition on writing at token. Fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a race condition on writing to **token**.

If you want to have a local array per block you can use shared memory. If you want a local array per thread, you will need to use local per-thread memory and declare the array on the stack. In the first case you will have to deal with concurrency inside the block as well. In the latter you don't have to, although you might potentially waste a lot more memory (and reduce collaboration).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Race conditions were surely happening. I instead just made an array inside the device. Since the array is only 5 bytes, I don't see a problem in each thread having it's own token variable.

Comment: if it's just 5 bytes I believe it's okay and if every thread has its own data ready. Local memory is fast if it can fit into registers without causing too much spilling.